# Como posso fazer um filtro lambda MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, expressões-lambda

Estou fazendo um filtro simples, e mostrar os dados na página.

O código que estou usando é esse:

```
mt.ModelItens = db.Forecast
                  .Where(f => (f.CanalForecast.area == idArea && f.CanalForecast.despesa == idDespesa))
                  .ToPagedList(mt.ModelPaging.page, mt.ModelPaging.pageSizeSelected);
```

Esse código funciona muito bem se os dois campos forem selecionados, pois se apenas um for selecionado não mostra nada.

Referente aqui:

```
.Where(f => (f.CanalForecast.area == idArea && f.CanalForecast.despesa == idDespesa))
```

Meu problema é que quero que funcione selecionando um campo ex. (Area) e também funcione selecionando os dois campos (Area e Despesa).

Não sei se agora consegui passar o real problema.

Comment: Dê mais informações, tá faltando contexto, informações de como os dados estão estruturas e clareza no objetivo do problema e dúvida existente.

Comment: user34200 você se registou como Edgar Araujo?

Comment: Acho que ele entrou por OAuth de duas formas diferentes e não unificou os usuários.

Answer (score 2):

Melhor você segmentar essa pesquisa, testando o que está preenchido:

```
var query = db.Forecast;
if (idArea != null) {
    query = query.Where(f => f.CanalForecast.area == idArea);
}

if (idDespesa != null) {
    query = query.Where(f => f.CanalForecast.despesa == idDespesa);
}

mt.ModelItens = query
                .OrderByDescending(entity => entity.idForecast)
                .ToPagedList(mt.ModelPaging.page, mt.ModelPaging.pageSizeSelected);
```

Comment: Cigano, Obrigado pela ajuda, Mas dessa forma caso seleciono os dois não vai ter os dois filtro e sim apenas um correto?

Comment: Depende do que está preenchido. Se os dois estiverem, em teoria, os dois são usados como filtro. Se apenas um estiver, apenas um é usado como filtro, e assim por diante.

Comment: @EdgarAraujo Aparentemente este [user34200](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/34200/user34200) é seu também. Procure unificar os logins no seu painel do usuário. Aliás, alterei a resposta para refletir seu código. Obrigado.